# How to refer another table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, tapestry

I have two classes: `User` and `Video`:

```
@Entity    
class User{
    @Id
    int id;        
    String name;
}

@Entity
    class Video{
    @Id
    int id;        
    String url;
    User user;
}
```

When i use this I get the following error:

> Could not determine type for: User, at table: Video

I'm using Hibernate through Tapestry. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple: You need a `@ManyToOne` annotation on the `user` field:

```
@Entity
class Video {
    @Id
    int id;

    String url;

    @ManyToOne
    User user;
}
```

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) for more information.